# Правильное применение assert в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Правально ли я понимаю использование встроенного оператора **assert** в языке **Python**,что использование этого оператора полезен при разработке фреймворков, библиотек для того чтобы разработчик видел сообщение об ошибках удобно и понятно?

Comment: `assert` используется для проверки истинности выражения, фактически, это некий вид тестов. Подробнее, например, тут https://oracle-patches.com/coding/3664-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-assert-%D0%B2-python-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B7

Comment: ```assert``` может так же использоваться, например - как тест внутри вашей фанкции. Т.е. функция получает два аргумента ```list_1``` и ```list_2``` и условие, что длина первого аргумента должна быть больше длины второго. Т.е. вы пишете ```assert len(list_1) > len(list_2), ('Incorrect lengths')```, тем самым заменяете условный оператор ```if```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python

Comment: Правильно понимаете , полезен.